# Why is there no parallel `std::accumulate` in the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17, std, accumulate

I think it is confusing that there is no parallel version of [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) in the C++ standard. It appears to me that it would be trivial to implement it in parallel, for instance, based on OpenMP or SIMD instructions. Does anybody have a good explanation for why the standard committee chose to introduce a parallel version of `std::reduce` but not `std::accumulate`? Is it because of the different iterator types?

Comment: What you want is  `std::reduce`.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce

Comment: Hard question to ask here. Very often the answer to "Why is there no X in the Standard Library?" is an unsatisfying, "Because no one has written a proposal with a compelling reason for X's inclusion."

Comment: Maybe dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093773/c-stdaccumulate-with-policy-execution-is-not-found

Comment: Could a reason be that not all platforms can perform in parallel?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews   Nope.   The reason (as described in Nicol Bolas' answer below) is that parallelism requires that order of operations doesn't matter (e.g. the order that that elements of the range are accessed, and binary operation applied), and `std::accumulate()` requires a fixed order.   If the binary operation is commutative, parallelisation doesn't change the final result, only the way it is reached.  If an implementation doesn't support parallelisation, all parallelisation policies will typically have no net effect, and the algorithms will run sequentially.

Comment: FWIV, compilers can and do apply SIMD parallelization to `std::accumulate` if the accumulated function allows it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

They introduced `reduce` because `accumulate` *cannot* be parallelized as it was written.

The C++ standard defines the expected behavior of the various functions. `accumulate` is defined as follows:

> Computes its result by initializing the accumulator `acc` with the initial value `init` and then modifies it with `acc = std::move(acc) + *i` or `acc = binary_op(std::move(acc), *i)` for every
> iterator `i` in the range `[first, last)` **in order**.

Emphasis added. Those two words make the algorithm unparallelizable. And because those words are part of the standard, users of `accumulate` are allowed to *rely* on the "in order" guarantee. They can make `operator+` or `binary_op` non-associative operations, ones that rely on the ordering of the operation. So the committee couldn't just take those words away without potentially breaking a bunch of code.

And they didn't want to have a parallel version of `accumulate` that had fundamentally different behavior from the non-parallel version. Therefore, `reduce` was introduced without the "in order" guarantee (and with other language that helped make it parallelizable).

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that even if `binary_op` was non-commutative, one could write a parallel version of std::accumulate as long as `binary_op` was associative, e.g. if `binary_op` was doing matrix multiplication.

Comment: Unparallelizable except within the limits of the as-if rule.  e.g. a compiler could still auto-vectorize `std::accumulate` over an array of `uint32_t` since it's truly associative, unlike FP addition.  GCC `-ftree-parallelize-loops=4` could even parallelize it if it expected it to be profitable (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/AutoParInGCC).  So the real benefit of `std::reduce` is for stuff like summing an FP array, or an FP dot product.  And to make thread-level parallelism explicit for the actual compiler/optimizer, not something it has to invent like it does for SIMD parallelism.

Comment: @10762409 Unfortunately, floating point arithmetic is not associative.